# small gap between google map and footer

Tags: html, css

Just implemented a google map to the website but there is a very small gap maybe 1-2px between the map and the footer. I was wondering if there was anyway to make them sit flush together and not have a tiny gap. Thanks for any help or advice. Not sure how i can solve this!

Maps and footer html

```
<iframe id="maps"
  width="100%"
  height="300px"
  padding="0px"
  margin="0px"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyB0d_sYwCWD5owhYY4UYb-i7VlOOnx2_o4

    &q=The Beckwood,Scunthorpe" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>

<footer id="myFooter">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <img id="footerlogo" src="assets/img/logo.png">

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h5>Thank you</h5>

                        <p>We would like to thank you for taking the time and visiting thebeckwood.co.uk. If you have any queries please don't hesitate to use the contact us button or give us a quick phone call.</p>
                         <img class="center" src="assets/img/hygeine.png">

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <h5>Navigation</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="book.html">Book</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="social-networks">
                        <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <a href="contact.html"> Contact us </a></button>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright">
            <p>© 2018 The Beckwood.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Footer CSS

```
#footerlogo {
    height:90px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#myFooter {
    background-color: #3d280c;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 30px

}

#myFooter .footer-copyright {
    background-color: #35240a;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}

#myFooter .row {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#myFooter .navbar-brand {
    margin-top: 45px;
    height: 65px;
}

#myfooter .navbar-brand>img {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
}

#myFooter .footer-copyright p {
    margin: 10px;
    color: #ccc;
}

#myFooter ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    line-height: 1.7;
}

#myFooter h5 {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: #FFB03B;;
    font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
}

#myFooter h2 a{
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

#myFooter a {
    color: #d2d1d1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#myFooter a:hover,
#myFooter a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFB03B;
}

#myFooter .social-networks {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}

#myFooter .social-networks a {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

#myFooter .social-networks a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#myFooter .facebook:hover {
    color: #002659;
}

#myFooter .google:hover {
    color: #ef1a1a;
}

#myFooter .twitter:hover {
    color: #00aced;
}

#myFooter .btn {
    color: white;
    background-color: #c48529;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

#myFooter .btn:hover {
    color: #593c12;
}
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] reproducing the issue we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
<style>iframe { display:block; } </style>
```

or

```
#maps {
    display: block;
}
```

in your case.

The default display property of an iframe is inline. That means they will be placed on the text baseline. The gap you're seeing is the space for alphabetic letters in the line of text. So it has nothing to do with Google Maps in particular.

Comment: Hi @yvo Linssen That worked perfectly. Would just like to thank you for taking your time to help me! I really appreciate it! Thanks to the others for helping too!

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number or reasons such as padding and margins set somewhere else.

You can move the footer up a bit by setting a `margin-top` to negative.

Although, try adding this:

```
#myFooter {
    background-color: #3d280c;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```